# jquery addClass function only fist half works

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have some links where I'd like to basically do a class swap.  When I have it set up like so it runs all the way through:

```
$("#work").click(function() {
    $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
    $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
    $(this).removeClass("notselected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");  


    a1=1;

    $("#top_section").animate({
        height:30
    },450);
    $("#bottom_section").animate({
        height:$("#grid").outerHeight(true)
    }, 450); 
    $("#about_container").animate({
        marginTop:$("#about_container").outerHeight(true) *-1
    }, 450);   

});
```

But when I try to set it up this way it runs the first two add and remove classes with the specific class, but the second two using 'this' don't work.  Is there a reason running it this way prevents 'this' from working?

```
function nav_click() {
    $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
    $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
    $(this).removeClass("notselected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");          
}    



$("#work").click(function() {
    nav_click();


    a1=1;

    $("#top_section").animate({
        height:30
    },450);
    $("#bottom_section").animate({
        height:$("#grid").outerHeight(true)
    }, 450); 
    $("#about_container").animate({
        marginTop:$("#about_container").outerHeight(true) *-1
    }, 450);   
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you checking the classes on `#work`?

Comment: well they should be fine because when I put the function contents directly into the work click function it works fine, but when I call it as a function written outside of the work click the 'this' name doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the function `nav_click()`, `this` is no longer what it was inside the click handler.  If you want to use the `nav_click()` function, then you must pass the value of `this` to that function.  You can either do that by causing `this` to be set appropriately inside the function:

```
nav_click.call(this);
```

Or, you can just pass it as an ordinary argument and change nav_click() to use that argument

```
nav_click(this);

function nav_click(item) {
    $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
    $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
    $(item).removeClass("notselected");
    $(item).addClass("selected");          
}
```

FYI, the value of `this` inside a function is determined by how that function is called.  If using just a normal function call like `nav_click()`, then `this` is reset to either the `window` object (normal JS mode) or to `undefined` (JS strict mode).

To explicitly cause `this` to be set to a particular value inside a function, use `.apply()` or `.call()`.  See the MDN pages for a description of these methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 0):

In the context of an anonymous event handler function, `this` references the element that the event is occurring to. For that reason, `this` does not reference what you think it means in the second context.

You could pass the element to the function, however:

```
function nav_click(element) {
    $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
    $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
    $(element).removeClass("notselected");
    $(element).addClass("selected");          
} 

$("#work").click(function() {
    nav_click(this);
    // etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are not passing anything in the callback function you just need to pass the element, this doen't refer to #work so you are unable to change the class do it this way...

```
function nav_click(element) {
    $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
    $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
    $(element).removeClass("notselected");
    $(element).addClass("selected");          
}    
    $("#work").click(function() {
    nav_click(this);


    a1=1;

    $("#top_section").animate({
        height:30
    },450);
    $("#bottom_section").animate({
        height:$("#grid").outerHeight(true)
    }, 450); 
    $("#about_container").animate({
        marginTop:$("#about_container").outerHeight(true) *-1
    }, 450);   
});
```